# PHP jquery refresh DIV

Tags: php, jquery, html, reload

I am working on refreshing a DIV with PHP and JQuery.  I am testing on the actual file that I will be using (a .php) and on a test.html file I made.  For some reason, the test.html file works yet the .php file does not.

test.html:

```
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); // This part addresses an IE bug. without it, IE will only load the first number and will never refresh
    setInterval(function() {
    $('#results').load('content.php');
    }, 3000); // the "3000" here refers to the time to refresh the div. it is in milliseconds.
    });
    // ]]></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="results">Loading users...</div>
</body>

</html>
```

view_conversation.page.inc.php (part of a messaging system):

```
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); // This part addresses an IE bug. without it, IE will only load the first number and will never refresh
    setInterval(function() {
    $('#list').load('content.php');
    }, 3000); // the "3000" here refers to the time to refresh the div. it is in milliseconds.
    });
    // ]]></script>
</head>
<?php



    $errors = array();
    $valid_conversation = (isset($_GET['conversation_id']) && validate_conversation_id($_GET['conversation_id']));
    if ($valid_conversation === false){
            $errors[] = 'Invalid Conversation ID.';
    }
    if (isset($_POST['message'])){
            if (empty($_POST['message'])){
                    $errors[] = 'You must enter a message.';
            }

            if (empty($errors)){
                    add_conversation_message($_GET['conversation_id'], $_POST['message']);
            }
    }

 if (empty($errors) === false){
        foreach ($errors as $error){
            echo $error;
        }
}


    if ($valid_conversation){
            /*if (isset($_POST['message'])){
                    update_conversation_last_view($_GET['conversation_id']);*/
                    $messages = fetch_conversation_messages($_GET['conversation_id']);
            }else{
                    $messages = array();
                    update_conversation_last_view($_GET['conversation_id']);
            }

   session_start();
$_SESSION['messages']=$messages; 
    ?>

    <a href="index.php?page=inbox">Inbox</a>
    <a href="index.php?page=logout">Logout</a>

            <form action="" method="post">
                    <p><textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="85"></textarea></p>
                    <p><input type="submit" value="Add Message" /></p>
            </form>

            <?php
            //var_dump( $messages );
            if($messages){
            ?><html><body>
            <div id='list'>Loading messages...</div>
            </body></html><?php





    }
    ?>
    </html>
```

My question is this: why does test.html work when view_conversation.inc.php doesn't (by the way, the content.php file just contains an echo for testing purposes)

Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you geting any error while loading .php file after refresh ?

Comment: no, the .php doesn't refresh at all, it just shows the original loading messages...

Comment: I also tried adding the div to the beginning of the php but got the same result

Comment: why are you including php in html tags in .php file.?

Comment: good spot.  I have changed it, however unfortunately it has not changed the result

Comment: Try `.append` or `.html` instead of `.load`

Comment: .append returns the loading message and then keeps on appending 'content.php' (not the contents, the file name).  .html does similar, except that it changes it to content.php rather than appending it

Comment: Try `<?php ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); ?>` at the first line to see if it outputs any errors.

Comment: It outputs: Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in /home/u406538221/public_html/delta/core/pages/view_conversation.page.inc.php on line 2 Notice: Undefined index: message_unread in /home/u406538221/public_html/delta/core/inc/private_message.inc.php on line 54.  The session_start() thing is probably because I use sessions for user login

Answer (score 0):

`session_start();` should be at the beginning of your PHP file, before any output. Try `<?php session_start(); ?>` at the top of your file. (before the `<html>` tag).

Comment: Thank you for that; it will be very useful later when I pass a variable through the session.  But for now the content.php is just echo 'test';

Comment: I just changed it.  I still get the same result.

Comment: but I understand it will definitely be important when I actually put proper content using variables from $_SESSION

Comment: Your code has two `<html>` tags. Remove the `<html>`, `<body>` and their closing tags from within the `if ($messages)` condition. Put your `<body>` tag before `<form>` and add the `</body>` before `</html>`

Comment: If you still get "Loading messages..." your javascript is not working.  Do you get any error in the console? Is jQUery loading properly?

Comment: Also, if the javascript were not working properly, surely it wouldn't work for test.html either